# Why does fopen() not recognize my file's name?

Tags: c, string, fopen, strstr

The programm should be able to open a file like `myFile.txt`,
alltough it's real name is `myFile` without the extension `.txt`.
So I wrote the `function` called `removeFileExtension()` in order
to achieve that.

It does open my file by copying the `string` from `text` into `filename`:

```
strcpy(filename,text);
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

So I tried to check what the difference between `text` and my processed
`string` from `removeFileExtension` is.

To check if it even works I mate a `function` called `strComparison()`,
which returns either `0` when it is qual or `1` if unequal.
The thing is, after removing the file extension, it shows that both strings
are qual, but I am still not able to open the file.

When I type in `./a.out myFile.txt` my comparison `function` returns `0`,
it is equal, but `fopen()` still is not able to open the file,
respectively I allways get a `Segmentation fault`.

Does anyone see the problem here?
Why am I getting a `Segmentation fault`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeFileExtension(char *haystack);
int strComparison(char *one, char *two);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // CHECK INPUT VALIDITY
  //
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: ./ass2 [file-name]\n");
    return 1;
  }


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // OPEN FILE (INITIAL)
  //
  char filename[32];
  strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");                                       //FOPEN
  //FILE *fp = fopen("start_of_story\0txt", "r");   // this way does work
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    // IF NOT FOUND: REMOVE EXTENSION
    removeFileExtension(filename);
    char text[] = "myFile\0";
    int ret_val = -1;
    ret_val = strComparison(filename, text);
    if (ret_val == 0)
      printf("[DEBUG] equal\n");
    else
      printf("[DEBUG] unequal\n");

    printf("[DEBUG] ret_val: %d\n", ret_val);
    printf("[DEBUG] '%s'\n", filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");                                     //FOPEN

    // IF STILL DOESN'T WORK: ERROR
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
      printf("[ERR] Could not read file %s.\n", filename);
      return 3;
    }
  }


  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // READ DATA (INITIAL)
  //
  int bufsize = 1024;
  char *buffer = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));                      //MALLOC
  if (!buffer)
  {
    printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
    return 2;
  }
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fread(buffer, bufsize, 1, fp);

  printf("[DEBUG] %s\n", buffer);
  fclose(fp);                                                           //FCLOSE

  free(buffer);
  buffer = NULL;
  return 0;
}

void removeFileExtension(char *haystack)
{
  char needle[1] = ".";
  char *retp;   // return pointer
  retp = strstr(haystack,needle);
  if (*retp == '.')
  {
    while (*retp != '\0')
    {
      *retp++ = '\0';
    }
    printf("[DEBUG] %s\n", haystack);
  }
}

int strComparison(char *one, char *two)
{
  do
  {
    printf("[DEBUG] '%c' == '%c'\n", *one, *two);
    if (*one++ != *two++)
    {
      return 1; // return 1 if unqual
    }
  }
  while ( (*one != '\0') || (*two != '\0') );
  return 0; // return 0 if qual
}
```

**Resulting output:**

```
user@host ~/Desktop $ ./a.out myFile.txt
[DEBUG] myFile
[DEBUG] 'm' == 'm'
[DEBUG] 'y' == 'y'
[DEBUG] 'F' == 'F'
[DEBUG] 'i' == 'i'
[DEBUG] 'l' == 'l'
[DEBUG] 'e' == 'e'
[DEBUG] equal
[DEBUG] ret_val: 0
[DEBUG] 'myFile'
[ERR] Could not read file myFile.
user@host ~/Desktop $
```

Comment: Warning: `char needle[1] = "."` is not a _string_.

Comment: Where are you getting the SegFault? Run your code in a debugger like gdb to find out as that is vital and valuable information in a question like this

Comment: as @SouravGhosh said, using strstr on needle will give you a segmentation fault, as 
    "."
 gets translated to 2 chars, including '\0' as the second char

Comment: Why are you *copying* the filename around?! Just use `argv[1]` in call to `fopen` and be done with it. It is even allowed to mutate `argv[1]`, for example to make it *shorter*.

Comment: also check your file system. It seems from your description like "start_of_story" exists, but "myFile" doesn't

Comment: So you are writing (possibly faulty) check functions to check whether you have implemented a function without faults? Smells like you need to learn to use a debugger!

Comment: `while ( (*one != '\0') || (*two != '\0') );` You access the shorter string beyond the `\0` byte.  Why don't you simply use `strcmp` instead of writing your own comparison function?

Comment: @Gerhardh I tried it with `strcmp()`, same result, it returns `0`, meaning that both are equal!

Comment: But `strcmp` would not access any string beyond its terminating 0 byte.

Comment: Why would you write `char text[] = "myFile\0";` when strings in C are already null-terminated? Please compile with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` for gods sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I found the problem: 
After removing the file's extension, I am still
trying to open the old file pointer `fp`, which
gave me the NULL-pointer back. The new file pointer
inside the body of the `if(fp == NULL){...}` only
exists inside the scope of the `if`-statement.

So I created a `test_pointer`, which first looks if
the file even exists, if not, he removes the extension.
Than I try again to open the file, this time with `fp`.

Thanks to everybody for the hints, especially to
[Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh)
for your improvement suggestions!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int removeFileExtension(char *haystack);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char filename[64];
  strcpy(filename, argv[1]);


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // CHECK INPUT VALIDITY
  //
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: ./ass2 [file-name]\n");
    return 1;
  }


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // CHECK FILE EXISTENSE
  //
  FILE *test_pointer = fopen(filename, "r");                             //FOPEN
  if (test_pointer == NULL)   // if not found: remove extension
  {
    int ret_val = removeFileExtension(filename);
    if (ret_val == -1)
    {
      printf("[ERR] Could not remove file extension.\n");
      return 3;
    }
  }


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // OPEN FILE (INITIAL)
  //
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");                                       //FOPEN
  if (fp == NULL)   // if still doesn't work: error
  {
    printf("[ERR] Could not read file %s.\n", filename);
    return 3;
  }


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // READ DATA (INITIAL)
  //
  int bufsize = 1024;
  char *buffer = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));                        //MALLOC
  if (!buffer)
  {
    printf("[ERR] Out of memory.\n");
    return 2;
  }
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fread(buffer, bufsize, 1, fp);
  fclose(fp);                                                           //FCLOSE

  printf("[DEBUG] %s\n", buffer);
  free(buffer);                                                           //FREE
  buffer = NULL;
  return 0;
}


int removeFileExtension(char *haystack)
{
  char needle[] = ".";
  char *retp;   // return pointer
  retp = strstr(haystack,needle);
  if(!retp)     // to prevent UB
    return -1;

  if (*retp == '.')
  {
    while (*retp != '\0')
    {
      *retp++ = '\0';
    }
    printf("[DEBUG] %s\n", haystack);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.24.5.7

> ```
> char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> The `strstr` function locates the first occurrence in the string pointed to by `s1` of the
>   sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null character) in the string pointed to
>   by `s2`.

So, both the arguments passed to `strstr` has to be  *strings*. In your case,

```
 char needle[1] = ".";
```

is not a *string*. You did not allow the space for the *null-terminator*. Either use

- `char needle[2] = ".";`, at least, or,
- `char needle[ ] = ".";`, or,
- `char const* needle = ".";`

As a side effect, whenever the call to `removeFileExtension()` is reached, you'll face with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

That said, **beware!!**

You are doing something like

```
retp = strstr(haystack,needle);
  if (*retp == '.')
```

i.e., dereferencing the returned pointer from `strstr()`. If, `strstr()` returns a NULL pointer, you'll again be trapped in UB.

---

EDIT:

For those who still has confusion about *string*, check definition in chapter §7.1.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters **terminated by and including the first null
>   character.** [...]

Comment: Or `char const* needle = ".";`

Comment: @SouravGhosh 
According to your suggestion, I tried it with `char needle[2] = ".";` and `char needle[ ] = ".";, or,` and `char const* needle = ".";`. It still produces a `Segmentation fault.` In case of a returned NULL pointer I made a interception-statement: if(!retp){return -1;} and therefore its now a `int`-function, instead a `void`.

Comment: @PatrickSteiner Where do you get the segmentation fault? The UB in your compare function might well cause a segmentation fault.